# Cholesky solve for semi-definite system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, sparse-matrices, lu-decomposition

I am thinking about the following linear algebra problem:
$$ Ax = b $$
where $A$ is an $n$ by $n$ positive semi-definite matrix, in particular, it is rank $n-1$ with null space span$\{e=(1,1,\ldots,1)^\top\}$. We assume that $b$ is in the range of $A$ and we are looking for a solution $x$ in the range of $A$. The solution is unique.

I would like to assume that the Cholesky decomposition is given:
$$ A = CC^\top$$
where $C$ is lower triangular matrix. Because $A$ is rank $n-1$, the right bottom most entry of $C$ will satisfy that $C(n,n)=0$.

The new system I get is now
$$ CC^\top x = b$$
if we let $z=C^\top x$ and consider $Cz = b$, we can find first $n-1$ entries of $z$ by a lower triangular solve. The last entry of $z$ has to be zero because $C^\top$ is upper triangular and $C^\top(n,n) = 0$.

My problem is how do we do the next step, that is to find $x$ such that $e^\top x = 0$ and that
$$ C^\top x = z$$
Of course this can be solved by adding the equation $e^\top x = 0$ into the linear system. But is there a good way where we can exploit the upper triangular property of $C^\top$? If possible, I would also assume that $C$ is sparse, it would be better if we could exploit the sparsity as well.

Comment: You are in the case of what is called an "incomplete Cholesky factorization"

Comment: @JeanMarie I know it is similar to the incomplete Cholesky. But my main problem is that C is not full rank while many incomplete Cholesky papers assume C is full rank.

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to do it. I can simply solve the system
$$ C^\top y = z$$
By assuming $y(n) = 0$, I can obtain a unique solution $y$ via upper triangular solve. The difference between $x$ and $y$ satisfies that
$$ C^\top (x-y) = 0$$
therefore it lives in the null space of $C^\top$, i.e. the span of $e$. That means
$$ x-y = c e$$
Notice that $e^\top x = 0$, we must have
$$ e^\top(x-y) = -e^\top y = c e^\top e = cn $$
so $c = mean(y)$, we can easily see that
$$ x = y - \bar{y} e $$
where $\bar{y}$ is the average of $y$.